# Dismiss standard permission dialog when permission is no longer needed

Tags: permissions, dialog, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

Every permission request will generate a standard dialog for it which can't be dismissed by clicking back button.
I want to know if it is possible to dismiss this standard permission dialog in case permission is no longer needed (and the user haven't choose yet to grant or deny it).

For example, an application of messaging and free calls like skype or viber. When I **receive a call** and the **record_audio** permission is **not granted**, the standard permission **dialog** will **show up**. Imagine that **the caller hunged up before I choose to grant or deny this permission**, in this case **requesting** this **permission** is **no longer needed** and the **dialog should dismiss**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary solution for my problem, waiting to google to provide us a way to dismiss the standard dialog.
The solution that I found is to restart the activity and it works fine for me until now.